# How to get this name with id after click submit button in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, form-submit

Now I want to get in radio this name with id when submit this form to upload this array of questions to database. What should I use in below code:

```
<form action="forms/handle-questions.php" method="post">
<?php foreach ($questions $key => $question) : ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?= $question['question'] ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check ">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_<?= $question['id'] ?>" 
                value="good">
         <label class="form-check-label"> good</label>
    </div>
    <div class=" form-check ">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_<?= $question['id'] ?>" 
                value="medium">
         <label class="form-check-label" >medium</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check ">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_<?= $question['id'] ?>"
                value="weak">
         <label class="form-check-label">weak</label>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
<button type="submit" name="handle_questions">Done</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should use a naming scheme like `name="radio[questionid]"` instead. Then `$_POST['radio']` will become an array, that you can loop over – and while doing that, you can _get_ the keys, without knowing them upfront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is something like this

in PHP after form post

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
 if (strpos($key, 'radio_') !== false) {
    $question_id = str_replace('radio_','',$key);
    // now you have the question id that this radio value applies to
 }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Works , Thank you